# No getter method for property id of bean

Tags: java, hibernate

I don't know what's wrong with this. When I'm using `"from Structure"`, it's working. But if I expand it to

```
"SELECT S.id, S.firstName, S.middleName, S.lastName, S.gender, S.birthdate, S.course, S.phone, S.address, S.classCode from StudentStructure S"
```

the error is:

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: No getter method for property id of bean showStudent
    at org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.lookup(RequestUtils.java:716)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.bean.WriteTag.doStartTag(WriteTag.java:290)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.crud.show_jsp._jspx_meth_bean_005fwrite_005f0(show_jsp.java:330)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.crud.show_jsp._jspService(show_jsp.java:165)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:387)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:469)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:403)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:301)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:972)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionForward(RequestProcessor.java:408)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:269)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1109)
    at com.getcare.utility.web.GetcareActionServlet.process(GetcareActionServlet.java:139)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:452)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:179)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:525)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:241)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:437)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpProtocol.java:381)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
10:52:50,230 INFO  [STDOUT] - Servlet.service() for servlet action threw exception
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: No getter method for property id of bean showStudent
    at org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.lookup(RequestUtils.java:716)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.bean.WriteTag.doStartTag(WriteTag.java:290)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.crud.show_jsp._jspx_meth_bean_005fwrite_005f0(show_jsp.java:330)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.crud.show_jsp._jspService(show_jsp.java:165)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:387)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:469)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:403)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:301)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:972)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionForward(RequestProcessor.java:408)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:269)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1109)
    at com.getcare.utility.web.GetcareActionServlet.process(GetcareActionServlet.java:139)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:452)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:179)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:525)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:241)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:437)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpProtocol.java:381)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

THIS IS THE STRUCTURE:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.getcare.remote.Structure;

/**
 * 
 * @author clemjon
 *
 * @hibernate.class table="student"
 */

public class StudentStructure extends Structure implements Serializable{

    private Integer id;
    private Integer phone,classCode;
    private String firstName, middleName, lastName, gender, birthdate, course,address;
    private ArrayList students;
    StudentContactInfoStructure contact = new StudentContactInfoStructure();

    public ArrayList getStudents() {
        return students;
    }
    public void setStudents(ArrayList arrayList) {
        this.students = arrayList;
    }
    /**
     * @hibernate.id generator-class="sequence"
     * @hibernate.generator-param name="sequence" value="student_id_seq"
     */


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }




    /**
     * @hibernate.property
     *
     */

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }




    /**
     * @hibernate.property
     * 
     */


    public String getMiddleName() {
        return middleName;
    }
    public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
        this.middleName = middleName;
    }




    /**
     * @hibernate.property
     * 
     */

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }




    /**
     * @hibernate.property
     * 
     */

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }




    /**
     * @hibernate.property
     * 
     */

    public String getBirthdate() {
        return birthdate;
    }

    public void setBirthdate(String birthdate) {
        this.birthdate = birthdate;
    }



    /**
     * @hibernate.property
     * 
     */

    public String getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public void setCourse(String course) {
        this.course = course;
    }



    /**
     * @hibernate.property
     * 
     */

    public Integer getPhone(){
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(Integer phone){
        this.phone = phone;
        this.contact.setPhone(phone);
    }




    /**
     * @hibernate.property
     * 
     */

    public String getAddress(){
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address){
        this.address = address;
        this.contact.setAddress(address);
    }


    /**
     * @hibernate.property
     * 
     */

    public Integer getClassCode(){
        return classCode;
    }

    public void setClassCode(Integer classCode) {
        this.classCode = classCode;
    }
}
```

AND THIS IS THE JSP:

```
<strike>
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=EUC-KR" pageEncoding="EUC-KR"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-form.tld" prefix="form" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld" prefix="logic" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %>

 <jsp:useBean id="studentForm" class="com.getcare.crud.web.StudentForm" scope="session"/>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<form:html >
<head>
<title>Show Student</title>
<script>
    function validate()
    {    
      var confirmMessage="All record of the student will be deleted. Click OK to continue.";
      if(confirm(confirmMessage)==false)
      {
          return false;
      }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table border=1>
        <thead>
            <tr bgcolor="#3CB371">
                <th>Student Number</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Middle Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>Birth Date</th>
                <th>Course</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Subject</th>
                <th colspan=2>Action</th>
                <th colspan=2>Add</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
       <% int count = 0; %>


       <logic:iterate id="showStudent" name="studentForm" property="students">

        <tbody>
                <tr bgcolor="#E0FFFF">

                    <td><bean:write name="showStudent" property="id"/></td>
                    <td><bean:write name="showStudent" property="firstName"/></td>
                    <td><bean:write name="showStudent" property="middleName"/></td>
                    <td><bean:write name="showStudent" property="lastName"/></td>
                    <td><bean:write name="showStudent" property="gender"/></td>
                    <td><bean:write name="showStudent" property="birthdate"/></td>
                    <td><bean:write name="showStudent" property="course"/></td>
                    <td><bean:write name="showStudent" property="phone"/></td>
                    <td><bean:write name="showStudent" property="address"/></td>
                    <td><bean:write name="showStudent" property="classCode"/></td>
                    <td><a href="/orprovider/crud/updateForm.do?id=<bean:write name="showStudent" property="id" format="##########"/>&firstName=<bean:write name="showStudent" property="firstName" format="##########"/>&middleName=<bean:write name="showStudent" property="middleName" format="##########"/>&lastName=<bean:write name="showStudent" property="lastName" format="##########"/>&gender=<bean:write name="showStudent" property="gender" format="##########"/>&birthdate=<bean:write name="showStudent" property="birthdate" format="##########"/>&course=<bean:write name="showStudent" property="course" format="##########"/>&classCode=<bean:write name="showStudent" property="classCode" format="##########"/>&phone=<bean:write name="showStudent" property="phone" format="##########"/>&address=<bean:write name="showStudent" property="address" format="##########"/>">Update</a></td>
                    <td><a href="/orprovider/crud/crudAction.do?method=delete&classCode=<bean:write name="showStudent" property="id" format="##########"/>" onclick="return validate()">Delete</a></td>
                    <td><a href="/orprovider/crud/forwardAdd.do?id=<bean:write name="showStudent" property="id" format="##########"/>&firstName=<bean:write name="showStudent" property="firstName" format="##########"/>&middleName=<bean:write name="showStudent" property="middleName" format="##########"/>&lastName=<bean:write name="showStudent" property="lastName" format="##########"/>&gender=<bean:write name="showStudent" property="gender" format="##########"/>&birthdate=<bean:write name="showStudent" property="birthdate" format="##########"/>&course=<bean:write name="showStudent" property="course" format="##########"/>&phone=<bean:write name="showStudent" property="phone" format="##########"/>">Class / Contact Info</a></td>
                </tr>     
        </tbody>
        <% count++; %>
        </logic:iterate> 

    </table>
     Records found: <%=count %> <br />
 <form:link href="http://orgetcare/orprovider/crud/options.do">Return to Options</form:link>

</body>
</form:html>
</strike>
```

STUDENT FORM:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import net.sf.hibernate.mapping.Collection;

import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;

import com.getcare.crud.remote.StudentContactInfoStructure;
import com.getcare.crud.remote.StudentStructure;

public class StudentForm extends ActionForm{

    private StudentStructure student = new StudentStructure();
    private StudentContactInfoStructure studentContact = new StudentContactInfoStructure();
    private ArrayList students = new ArrayList();
    private ArrayList studentContacts = new ArrayList();
    private int studentid;
//  private ArrayList s= new ArrayList();


//  public ArrayList getS() {
//      return (ArrayList) Arrays.asList(students,studentContacts);
//  }

//  public void setS(ArrayList s) {
//      this.s = (ArrayList) Arrays.asList(students,studentContacts);
//  }

    public int getId() {
        return student.getId();
    }

    public void setId(int id){
        student.setId(id);
        studentContact.setId(student.getId());
//      studentContact.setStudentid(id);
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        student.setFirstName(firstName);
    }

    public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
        student.setMiddleName(middleName);
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        student.setLastName(lastName);
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        student.setGender(gender);
    }

    public void setBirthdate(String birthdate) {
        student.setBirthdate(birthdate);
    }

    public void setCourse(String course) {
        student.setCourse(course);
    }

    public void setPhone(Integer phone){
        student.setPhone(phone);
        studentContact.setPhone(phone);
    }

    public void setAddress(String address){
        student.setAddress(address);
        studentContact.setAddress(address);
    }

    public void setClassCode(Integer classCode) {
        student.setClassCode(classCode);
    }


    public String getFirstName() {
        return student.getFirstName();
    }

    public String getMiddleName() {
        return student.getMiddleName();
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return student.getLastName();
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return student.getGender();
    }

    public String getBirthdate() {
        return student.getBirthdate();
    }

    public String getCourse() {
        return student.getCourse();
    }

    public Integer getPhone(){
        return student.getPhone();
    }

    public String getAddress(){
        return student.getAddress();
    }

    public Integer getClassCode(){
        return student.getClassCode();
    }


    public Integer getStudentid() {
        return studentContact.getId();
    }

    public void setStudentid(int studentid) {
        studentContact.setId(student.getId());
        studentContact.setStudentid(studentid);
    }

    @Override
    public void reset(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request) {
        super.reset(mapping, request);
//      setId(0);
        setFirstName(null);
        setLastName(null);
        setMiddleName(null);
        setGender(null);
        setBirthdate(null);
        setCourse(null);
        setPhone(null);
        setAddress(null);
        setClassCode(null);
    }



    public ArrayList getStudents() {
        return student.getStudents();
    }
    public void setStudents(ArrayList students) {
        this.student.setStudents(students);
    }


    public ArrayList getStudentContacts() {
        return studentContact.getStudentContacts();
    }
    public void setStudentContacts(ArrayList studentContacts) {
        this.studentContact.setStudentContacts(studentContacts);
    }

    public StudentContactInfoStructure getStudentContact() {
        return studentContact;
    }

    public void setStudentContact(StudentContactInfoStructure studentContact) {
        this.studentContact = studentContact;
    }

    public StudentStructure getStudent() {
        return student;
    }

    public void setStudent(StudentStructure student) {
        this.student = student;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you look at the exception? Please post your jsp, the type of the attribute `showStudent`.

Comment: We need to see your class `StudentStructure` (and if your class just represents a student, call it `Student`; in Java, everything's a class, and labeling things "class" or "structure" isn't customary).

Comment: this also works:    select sc from StudentStructure sc